# Unable to start computer with Hyper-V (hypervisorlaunchtype auto) and CPU Virtualization enabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have enabled Virtualization (VMX) and addtionally a setting called vt-d in my Asus Z390-E motherboard bios settings.

Boot the computer, enable Hyper-V from the turn Windows features on/off menu. This requires a restart. When restarting windows will not boot. The only way to fix it while still keeping Virtualization on is to boot into safe mode and running the following command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Now I am at a point where I have Virtualization and vt-d enabled and I am able to boot windows successfully.

My remaining problem is that when trying to start up a virtual server with Hyper-V it says Hypervisor is not running. I was hoping there would be a way to turn hypervisor on after windows has started, but I don't think that is possible since it needs to be turned on at an early stage.

Windows 10 - Completely up to date,
Asus Z390-E Bios - Completely up to date

I am aware with my current setup I can use Oracle VM Virtual Box since it doesn't rely on hypervisor. However, I prefer using built int Windows Hyper-V.

Does anyone have any additional things I can try? It must be something specific to my setup with absolute latest version of Windows 10 and motherboard because no one else is experiencing this issue.

If I change the following setting back to auto:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

It will require a restart and put me back into the same boat where I get the blue screen saying windows is unable to start.

Comment: "My remaining problem is that when trying to start up a virtual server with Hyper-V it says Hypervisor is not running." - You are getting this error due to the fact the Hypervisor is indeed not running, you have specifically booted into Windows, with the Hypervisor off.  I would reinstall Hyper-V

Comment: What problem are you encountering when booting with `hypervisorlaunchtype auto`?

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe I guess didn't word my post clear enough. If I change hypervisor launchtype to auto and restart the PC while virtualization is enabled windows will not boot (blue screen that says restore to an earlier point in time, trying running startup repair and keeps failing etc...). I have uninstalled and re-installed Hyper-V several times playing around with different launchtype values for hypervisor and virtualization settings in the BIOS.

Comment: @harrymc I get the Windows 10 Blue screen that asks to restore to an earlier point in time, I hit cancel, go to advanced and I am able to boot in safe mode to set hypervisorlaunchtype back to off. Then windows will start. The main problem is that windows does not boot when hypervisor tries to launch pre-desktop and virtualization is enabled. I am convinced this issue is specific to my Asus motherboard and absolute latest version of Windows 10. Either a bios update or windows update will resolve it overtime.

Comment: See if you can show us the analysis of the crash using [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), and if not then just a screenshot of the blue screen itself.

Comment: @BlakeRivell “Absolute latest” - What version is that exactly?  You can have a cumulative update installed this week and still be on 1507. So I assume your talking about 1903 instead of 19H2 or 20H1?  I was just pointing out that until you enable the Hypervisor within Windows Hyper-V won’t work.

Comment: @Ramhound 1903 is the version of Windows.

Comment: @BlakeRivell interested in your problem. I m having the reverse issue where Windows freeze without errors when set to off.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with Lenovo ThinkPad P15 G1. In the end I used the Lenovo System Update tool to update all the drivers, then set "hypervisorlaunchtype auto", and finally it started working.